# Is this order correct? Using biblatex-chicago.sty

Tags: biblatex-chicago

My codes are follows:

`content of test.bib`

```
@article{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:11:35 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-05 23:44:19 +0100},
Journal = {Cognition},
Number = {3},
Pages = {329--349},
Title = {Action Understanding as Inverse Planning},
Volume = {113},
Year = {2009}}

@inproceedings{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06,
Author = {C. L. Baker and J. Tenenbaum and R. Saxe},
Booktitle = {Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems},
Date-Added = {2014-01-30 12:16:28 +0100},
Date-Modified = {2014-02-01 00:11:49 +0100},
Publisher = {Cambridge, MA: MIT Press},
Title = {Bayesian Models of Human Action Understanding},
Volume = {18},
Year = {2006}}
```

`content of test.tex`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[notes,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}%
\makeatletter
\AtEveryBibitem{\global\undef\bbx@lasthash}%
\makeatother
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{baker_saxe_tenenbaum09} and \textcite{baker_tenenbaum_saxe06}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

I just want to confirm the ordering of the references are correct? As, both entries `author names` are same, and the year only different. I thought that the year `2006` entry should come first, but I'm not sure. Any expert confirm please...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Yes, this appears to be correct behaviour for a bibliography in Chicago style.

---

`biblatex-chicago`'s `notes` style sorts by name (`author`, `editor`, ...), `title` and `year` in that order.

Since `baker_saxe_tenenbaum09`'s 'Action' sorts before `baker_tenenbaum_saxe06`'s 'Bayesian' the order appears to be correct according to the specified sorting scheme.

From §14.68: *The 3-em dash for one repeated name* of the [Online CMS](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html)

> For successive entries by the same author, editor, translator, or compiler [... a]lphabetization is by title of work (abbreviations such as ed. or trans., which must always be included, do not influence the order of entries).
>
> [**Example**]
>
> Judt, Tony. A Grand Illusion? An Essay on Europe. New York: Hill and Wang, 1996.
> ———. Reappraisals: Reflections on the Forgotten Twentieth Century. New York: Penguin Press, 2008.
> ———, ed. Resistance and Revolution in Mediterranean Europe, 1939–1948. New York: Routledge, 1989.
>
> [...]

Where clearly the example sorts by titles and not by year.

There is also §14.71: *Alphabetical order for titles by the same author*

> In a bibliography (as opposed to a reference list; see 15.18), titles by the same author are normally listed alphabetically. [...] Note that all works by the same person (or by the same persons in the same order)—whether that person is editor, author, translator, or compiler—appear together, regardless of the added abbreviation.

Note that a *bibliography* created with the `notes` style is different from a *reference list* created with the `authordate` style (where citations are in author-year format). A reference list is sorted by author, year and title in that order (which makes sense, because citations in a document with a reference list are in author-year form).

Comment: Much thanks sir...